# Error in node module: fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2BE03E

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, gatsby

I installed Gatsby and started using the [Casper Gatsby Starter Kit](https://github.com/cbillowes/gatsby-starter-casper).

I did get it added and `npm install` was successful. When I tried a new project I kept getting errors. I though it was because of my internet connection.

After a bunch of retries I finally got this error which was consistent: 
**fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2BE03E**

```
C:\Users\<USER>\.node-gyp\9.5.0\x64\node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2BE03E C:\<PROJECT>\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\node_modules\sharp\build\libvips-cpp.vcxproj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the contents of `.node-gyp` (found in user folder) and it worked.